# DataTables - Not case-sensitive ordering

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have this datatable definition

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                var table = $('#producersTableId').DataTable({
                    "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {"targets": [0], "width": '25%'},
                        {"targets": [1], "width": '40%'},
                        {className: "dt-body-center" , "targets": [2], "width": '5%'},
                        {className: "dt-body-center" , "targets": [3], "width": '30%'},                        
                    ]                    
                });
                table.columns().every( function () {
                    var that = this;
                    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                            that
                                .search( this.value )
                                .draw();
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            });
```

Is there a way in the `"order": [[1, 'asc']],`  option to ignore case in the order (Not case-sensitive ordering) ?

Comment: DataTables is already using non case-sensitive ordering, see https://jsfiddle.net/seo3d9jc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38495 and http://live.datatables.net/qobihina/1/edit. The code is from an example on

```
Please see https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38495 and http://live.datatables.net/qobihina/1/edit. The code is from an example on 

/* JAVASCRIPT */
$(document).ready( function () { var table = $('#example').DataTable(); } );

/* HTML */
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand I am digging it after ages. But facing the same issue.
The link shared by you works fine. But If I try to just replace the names and try sorting 
it by names it doesn't work with case-sensitivity. :(
Link: http://live.datatables.net/qobihina/75/edit
Not sure if this link contains the data with the names I have replaced. Hence pasting the data below.

```
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>roger</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Roger David</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>rogere</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Roger</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>roger</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>roger</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This does not appear to be an answer but rather a question. Please open a new question with MRE. See how to formulate questions to receive good answers - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example